# properly interpreting Pi_0 in the homotopy exact sequence

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, homotopy-theory

Define the lens space L(m,n) as the quotient of S<sup>2m+1</sup> by the action of the cyclic group ℤ<sub>n</sub>⊂S<sup>1</sup>⊂ℂ*.  We can create the infinite lens space L(∞,n) by a telescoping construction on the lens spaces L(m,n) for fixed n, which has as an n-sheeted covering space S<sup>∞</sup>.  The homotopy exact sequence is then

... --> π<sub>1</sub>(S<sup>∞</sup>) --> π<sub>1</sub>(L(∞,n)) --> π<sub>0</sub>(n points) --> π<sub>0</sub>(S<sup>∞</sup>) --> ...

Here, π<sub>1</sub>(S<sup>∞</sup>) is the trivial group, and π<sub>0</sub>(S<sup>∞</sup>) is a set with one point.  The sequence is still exact at the π<sub>0</sub> portion, once we specify a basepoint for each set and call its preimage the kernel of the map, meaning that whatever π<sub>1</sub>(L(∞,n)) is, it definitely has n elements.  It's a group, too, so if n is prime then we have no choice but to conclude that π<sub>1</sub>(L(∞,n))=ℤ<sub>n</sub>.  Of course, even when n isn't prime, the fact of the matter is that this statement is still true.

But this is a little unsettling to me.  It seems like we're only concluding that because the deck group of the universal cover happens to be ℤ<sub>n</sub> (or, admitting the full extent of our complicity, because we're very nearly taking as a *definition* that L(∞,n)=S<sup>∞</sup>/ℤ<sub>n</sub>).  If we aren't working with the universal cover, then π<sub>1</sub> of the cover isn't trivial, so even if the cover is connected it seems like we could run into the extension problem in trying to compute π<sub>1</sub> of the base.  Of course, this is all algebraic; perhaps there's something geometric that will save the day and tell us how to interpret this.  Is that the case, or is there some other way to unambiguously determine π<sub>1</sub> of the base here (perhaps from the definition of the connecting homomorphism via the covering homotopy property)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a bit more structure in this long exact sequence that you can use.  If you have $F \to E \to B$, then on choosing a basepoint in $B$, then for any basepoint $e$ in $F$ you have the sequence

$\dots \to \pi_1 E \to \pi_1 B \to \pi_0 F \to \pi_0 E \to \pi_0 B$.

The extra structure is the fact that $\pi_1 B$  acts on $\pi_0 F$, through deck transformations, if $E\to B$ is actually a covering map, and that:

* the stabilizer group of $[e]$ in $\pi_0F$ under this action is the image of $\pi_1E \to \pi_1B$, and

* the set of orbits $\pi_0F/\pi_1B$ under this action is exactly the "kernel" of $\pi_0E\to \pi_0B$.

Thus, if you have some non-trivial extension and are trying to compute $\pi_1B$, then you get to use the information about deck transformations.  I don't know what more to say without an explicit example.